# Configure Marathon to not restart tasks that enter TASK_FINISHED

Tags: mesos, marathon

I launch tasks via Marathon. However they finish, Marathon restarts them. I would like them to only restart if they finish in failure. Is there a way such that if the task enters the state of TaskStatus.TASK_FINISHED that Marathon will not restart it, e.g., by suspending the job, i.e., by setting the number of tasks to zero?

Currently when my task completes successfully I PUT a message to the Marathon REST API scaling the job down to 0 instances. This is fine except that in response Marathon kills the task setting its status to TASK_KILLED and I would like it to be TASK_FINISHED to indicate its success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one-of tasks as you describe, I think the better solution would be to use a scheduler like

- https://mesos.github.io/chronos/ or its successor
- https://github.com/dcos/metronome

Marathon is normally used to keep tasks running, and rescheduling them if they reach a final task state.

See the [Marathon docs](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/), and also [this explanation of different task types](https://aster.is/blog/2015/10/07/whats-a-long-running-task/).

Comment: I think it's wort to mention [Singularity](https://github.com/HubSpot/Singularity)

Comment: @janisz IMO Singularity is a much broader solution, but thanks for mentioning!

Comment: I guess I don't see this as a one-of task because I do want restarts in the case of failures. Perhaps one of the solutions you mention or Singularity does that? I'll take a look. Still, it does seem odd to me that a Marathon launched task can only end in a failed, aborted or killed state and never finished (which I assume is the success state). If you can definitively state that that is the case and add it to your answer then I will accept it.

Comment: It is a one-of task in the sense that you want it finished at a certain point in time and NOT having it restarted. That's not what Marathon is used for normally... I added a reference to the Marathon docs in the answer.